# How to Debug "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key " for TFS 2005

Tags: tfs

I am unable to checkin changes to our TFS 2005 and get the following error while I check in .

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key

How do I debug, I checked the eventviewer and but no related errors. Any Ideas on Debugging the error. Am I missing any Files etc....

Answer (score 0):

Contact the server administrator - possibly there is a custom checkin policy that you don't have on your local machine.